# ¿MVC 4, Cómo agrego validación a un detailsview con una entrada de usuario para consultar?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

El Detailsview muestra cierta info de la DB donde el usuario introduce un dato a traves de un textbox. Quiero que muestre error cuando el usuario no introduzca nada y clicke el botón.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es muy clara su pregunta así que me voy a arriesgar a dar una respuesta que creo lo puede ayudar a establecer su real necesidad.

Una posibilidad muy útil quienes desarrollamos aplicaciones ASP.NET MVC es la posibilidad de usar “Data Annotations” para hacer validaciones de campos desde el modelo.

El framework MVC incluye algunos Data Annotations muy utiles que podemos usar en nuestros desarrollos como atributos para validar:

**Campos requeridos**,  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

**Longitudes de campo**s, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

**Expresiones regulares**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx
etc. Toda la lista de atributos la puedes encontrar en la documentación del namespace 
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.

Por ejemplo:

```html
//Campo obligatorio
[Required] 
public string Title { get; set; }

// Longitud minima requerida
[Required, StringLength(50)]
public string Title { get; set; }

// Rango permitido
[Range(1, 10000)]
public decimal StartPrice { get; set; }
```

Sugier ver este link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/ee256141(v=vs.100).aspx

En el caso de ser necesario validaciones más complejas debe hacerlo mediante con IValidatableObject

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1083/aspnet-mvc-self-validation-model-objects